# Running heroku local results in SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, django, heroku

When I run `heroku local` in terminal it throws this error:

```
22:01:24 web.1   |    File "manage.py", line 17
22:01:24 web.1   |      ) from exc
22:01:24 web.1   |           ^
22:01:24 web.1   |  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
22:01:24 web.1   Exited with exit code null
```

I am following this [tutorial](https://realpython.com/django-hosting-on-heroku/#step-1-scaffold-a-django-project-for-hosting). Not sure if it helps but here is my Procfile contents:

```
web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

My Python version is `3.9.9`

Comment: did you activate virtualenv?

Comment: Yep im in my virtual environment

Comment: make sure you have installed Django in venv with ```pip list```

Comment: I checked this and it was installed but I didn't use ``pipenv`` I used ``pip3`` to install. When I ran ``which python`` it revealed I was installing dependencies to ``/usr/bin/python`` rather than my venv. This may be the problem?

Comment: that means your virtualenv isn't activated yet, delete that venv and create another one

Comment: The issue may be related to a virtual environment not being active, but since this is a `SyntaxError` the core issue is likely that you're using an old version of Python. For example, `/usr/bin/python` might be an old Python 2.7.